# Getting error on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting following error on my jsp. May be it's appearing due to session timeout but how to handle it:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /navbar.jsp at line 23
```

And my code is:

```
20:                         <li><a href="homepage.jsp"><i class="icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
21: 
22:                         <li><a href="MenuTeamMember.jsp"><i class="icon-group"></i> Team</a></li>
23:                         <%if (session.getAttribute("role").equals("National_Head") || session.getAttribute("role").equals("Admin")) {%>
24:                         <li class="dropdown">
25:                             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-globe"></i> Distribution<b class="caret"></b></a>
26:                             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Comment: My guess would be that `session.getAttribute("role")`returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to come out of this:

1.Check for `session.getAttribute("role")`  `null` or not

2)`getAttribute` returns `Object`,So you dhould cast it to `String` to check.

```
 <%if ((String)session.getAttribute("role").equals("National_Head") ||
                   (String)session.getAttribute("role").equals("Admin")) {%>
```

3)Immeadiatly read :  [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: If getAttribute returns Object than no problem for equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `session.getAttribute("role")` may return `null`. Change your condition like below than see what is happend.

```
<%if ("National_Head".equals(session.getAttribute("role")) 
     ||       "Admin".equals(session.getAttribute("role")) {%>
```

In case of String `equals` first use fixed value (i.e "National_Head") which will never throw any `NPE`.

Comment: `getAttribute returns Object`. Not `String`.

Comment: And `equals` method want an `Object`, so it should be fine.